# Swagger UI is appending application server port number with DNS provided URL

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using Swagger 2.8.0 to generate the Spring Boot Rest API documentation.

But it is returning the DNS name with aplication server port , which is unexpected.

So My application structure is

```
DNS URL ( like www.myweb.com) -> web server (like abcserver:1234) -> app server (like xyzserver:5678).
```

So while accessing the Swagger UI from DNS name, it is returning appication server port appended with host name. So I am getting `www.myweb.com:5678` as host name in Swagger UI, which is wrong.

But it is working fine while using web serer with port or application server with port. as a example , if I hit `https://xyzserver:5678/**Swagger-ui.html` then it is returning correct host name , like `xyzserver:5678` here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue related to Apache server. Nothing to be done on Swagger .